# Поместить строку в нарисованный круг и менять размер обоих обьектов Qt

Tags: qt5

Всем привет.
Сталкнулся с такой проблемой, имеется переопределенный метод 
::paint(QPainter *painter)

В нем я рисую круг, и мне надо по центру поместить строку, которая представляет из себя время.
Крул можно изменить в размере растягивая. Но как сделать так, чтоыб и строка со временем изменяла размер?
Ниже привожу код

```
//Draw object
QBrush  brushNonActiveFull(nonActiveColorFull_);
QBrush  brushHours(borderHoursColor_);


painter->setPen(Qt::NoPen);
painter->setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);

/////////Circle///////

QRectF outerRect1(boundingRect().adjusted(0,0,0,0));
QRectF innerRect1(boundingRect().adjusted(8,8,-8,-8));

QPainterPath path1;
path1.moveTo(outerRect1.center().x(), 0);
path1.arcTo(outerRect1, 90, 360);
path1.arcTo(innerRect1, 90, 360);
path1.closeSubpath();
painter->fillPath(path1, brushNonActiveFull);

QPainterPath path2;
path2.moveTo(outerRect1.center().x(), 0);
path2.arcTo(outerRect1, 90, angleOfRotationFull_);
path2.arcTo(innerRect1, 90 + angleOfRotationFull_, -angleOfRotationFull_);
path2.closeSubpath();
painter->fillPath(path2, brushHours);

/////////Time///////

QPainterPath path5;
QPoint point(70, 140);
auto time = QTime::currentTime();

QFont outline_font(QLatin1String("times"), 14);
QFontMetrics fm(outline_font);

path5.addText(point, outline_font, time);
painter->fillPath(path5, brushMinutes);
```

Заранее спасибо всем.

Comment: В строке **QFont outline_font(QLatin1String("times"), 14);** значение 14 менять в зависимости от изменения радиуса круга. Другой способ это менять значение **QFont::setPixelSize**. Надо поэкспериментировать

Comment: А как правильно расположить по центру? Это для меня сейчас первостепенное.